# Frozen Linux Recovery Without SysReq

Tags: linux, reboot

RHEL system has run out of memory and is now frozen. The SysReq commands are not working, so I am not even sure that /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq is set to 1. Is there any other "safe" way I can reboot w/out power cycling?

Comment: Define "frozen". Did it panic? Or did something else happen?

Comment: The Big Red Button should unwedge it enough to shut down (somewhat) normally; if not, waiting a while for activity to drain and pulling the plug might be the only option. Oh, and make _sure_ you know how this happened so it won't happen again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's completely unresponsive. It didn't panic, it just ran out of memory. The last update to a top display showed 0 bytes of swap and a couple of kb of physical memory.